# Open Chrome (or Firefox, Opera etc.), fill login and password using wpf application

Tags: wpf

I want to run my Chrome(example : System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.abc123.com");) from WPF application and then fill fields (password and login) automatically, but i DO NOT want to use something like webbrowser control.

Thx for help

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download a [WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and the [chrome driver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/).
Include the dlls in your project and you are good to go.
Short exmaple:

```
IWebDriver  driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Download\chromedriver"); 
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.abc123.com"); 
IWebElement myField = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login"));      
myField.SendKeys("username");
```

For more information see [this tutorial](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2013/01/18/selenium-webdriver-using-chrome-webdriver-in-visual-studio-c/).